# how to highlight a word given coordinates

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, coordinates

I found this code: ([result of the script](http://jsfiddle.net/5gyRx/)):

HTML

```
<p>Each word will be wrapped in a span.</p><p>A second paragraph here.</p>Word: <span id="word"></span>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
// wrap words in spans
$('p').each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.html($this.text().replace(/\b(\w+)\b/g, "<span>$1</span>"));
});


// bind to each span
$('p span').hover(
    function() { $('#word').text($(this).css('background-color','#ffff66').text()); },
    function() { $('#word').text(''); $(this).css('background-color',''); }
);
```

I would like something similar. What I need to do is to obtain the same result but instead of highlighting the word (span tag) under the cursor I need to highlight a word (span tag) given the coordinates in pixels.
Does anyone know if this is possible and how can I do it? Or is there another way?

Thank you!

Comment: I'm not sure to follow you, what do you want to highlight exactly? On which condition?

Comment: I have the coordinates and what I want to do is highlight the word located in the given coordinates. For example I have x and y and I want to know the word that is located in the x and y position on screen.

Comment: What would be the use case? It would be easier and more efficient to rely on the `hover` event rather than computing the coordinates.

Comment: I am using an eyetracker and I get the coordinates of the gaze from a database. What I want is to highlight the word that the user is looking at.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you want to use [elementFromPoint()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.elementFromPoint). It's really simple to use, you need to pass the coordinates and this function will return an element under the point.

For your particular case, every word must be in an independent element `span`, `div` or whatever.

See the working example: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2gwtzpyn/)

Maybe you want to make some more robust solution, and add a condition if in the given coordinates there is not an element (`elementFromPoint()` return its ancestor or the `body` element or NULL if coordinates are not in visible part)

Comment: Thank you for your help! I tried your code and I changed the coordinates for the "first" button with (50, 70) and the first time I push the button it highlights the whole text, but after reseting it if I push the button again it seems that it works. I don't understand why...

Comment: Easy, because in (50,70) there is not an HTML with text `div` or `span` or whatever, `elementFromPoint()` is returning the `body` element. Therefore, changes will apply to all elements inside `body`

Answer (score 2):

This is relatively easy once every word token is wrapped in a span. You can use jQuery's `.position()`, `.width()` and `.height()` functions to determine if an element overlaps with a given set of x,y coordinates.

Something as simple as

```
var x = 100, y = 100;

$("span.token").filter(function () {
    var $this = $(this), pos = $this.position();

    return y >= pos.top && y <= pos.top + $this.height() && 
        x >= pos.left && x <= pos.left + $this.width();
})
```

finds the element(s) at position 100,100.

---

However. Your "wrap words in spans" function is wrong and potentially dangerous. It must be rewritten to a more complex, but in exchange safer approach.

I've created a `.tokenize()` jQuery plugin that walks the DOM tree and works on substitutes all text nodes it finds, wrapping them in a configurable bit of HTML:

```
$.fn.extend({
    // this function recursively tokenizes all text nodes in an element
    tokenize: function (wrapIn) {
        return this.not(".tokenized").each(function () {
            $(this).addClass("tokenized").children().tokenize(wrapIn);
            $(this).contents().each(function () {
                var node = this,
                    parent = this.parentNode,
                    tokens, tokenCount;

                // text node: tokenize, dissolve into elements, remove original text node
                if (node.nodeType === 3) {
                    tokens = $(node).text().replace(/\s+/g, " ").split(" ");
                    tokenCount = tokens.length;
                    $.each(tokens, function (i, token) {
                        if (token > "") {
                            parent.insertBefore($(wrapIn).text(token)[0], node);
                        }
                        if (i < tokenCount - 1) {
                            parent.insertBefore(document.createTextNode(" "), node);
                        }
                    });
                    parent.removeChild(node);
                }
            });
        });
    }
});
```

Usage:

```
$("p").tokenize("<span class='token'>");
```

---

See a live example here: http://jsfiddle.net/u5Lx6e2a/

Comment: Thank you very much!! It looks like the perfect solution for my project! I will try to adapt it to my programm and I will let you know if it works!! Thank you again!!